# How to add a node on different system as a peer in your private blockchain network?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, peers

I have created 2 nodes on different systems. I created accounts and was able to transfer ethers across accounts in the same node. Now i want to connect the 2 nodes on different system. I have used following commands for the nodes:

**Node 1:**

```
geth --networkid 100 --identity node1 --verbosity 3 --nodiscover --nat none --datadir "C:\Rahul\blockchain\node1"
```

**Node 2:**

```
geth --networkid 100 --identity node2 --port 30802 --rpcport 8902 --verbosity 3 --nodiscover --nat none --datadir "C:\Rahul\blockchain\node2"
```

Now i want to add node2 as a peer to node1. So i used "admin.addPeer(enode Address)".

```
admin.addPeer("enode://675908f0bbdcf8d19110dd84e0bfacbf60acd7c506c126213eedc71f315a95cdeb9a8f5
728832c37c9751ed74803141b9b07674bac015caebcbc73d7aef9798c@172.16.224.167:30802?discport=0")
```

here **172.16.224.167** is the IP of node2 i.e in another system and **30802** is the port it is listening to.

Now when i enter this command, following is the response i receive:

> **Error1:**
>   (anonymous): Line 1:15 Unexpected token ILLEGAL (and 2 more errors)

Please help me connect these two nodes or instruct me as to where is the mistake.

Comment: See https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9701/how-do-i-set-up-2-private-mining-nodes-on-the-same-computer.

Answer (score 1):

First: Take out --nodiscover, it disables automatic node discovery, it would work much better without it. Unless you want to add every node manually.

Second: I guess you're inserting the addpeer command in the first node console...

Third: I would take out `?discport=0` from your addpeer command.

Forth: check there's no invisible characters in this string (it sometimes happens, as in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719859/no-visible-cause-for-unexpected-token-illegal)